# `match` and `exec` with non-global regex appear to return the first match twice

Tags: javascript, regex

I do not quite understand the behaviour of the JavaScript regex methods.

The problem is that I can’t get regexes of type `/(something|something)/` to work with the `match` or `exec` methods without the *global* identifier, e.g. `/(somereg1|somereg2)/g`.

When the *global* identifier is there, the methods correctly return every instance it finds. But when it is not there, both methods correctly return only the first match they find. The problem is that they appear to return it twice. For instance:

```js
const str = "Here is somereg1 and somereg2";

str.match(/(somereg1|somereg2)/)
```

I would expect this `match` call to return `"somereg1"`. Instead it appears to return `"somereg1,somereg1"`.

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myf43ay1/). The code should be fairly self explanatory. The first example is taken from W3Schools.

Comment: First element in match array is full match by regex. 2nd element onwards you get all captured groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element is the full match of the regex. If you tried this:

```js
const str = "Here is somereg1 and somereg2";

str.match(/.*(somereg1|somereg2)/)
```

Your result would be `[ "Here is somereg1 and somereg2", "somereg2" ]`.

This same behaviour occurs with an `.exec(str)` method call.

You might want to read about [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

About the “sub parentheses matches”: in regexes, parentheses delimit [capture groups](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). So, if you had this regex:

```js
/.*(somereg1).*?(somereg2)/
```

Your `.match` result would be `[ "Here is somereg1 and somereg2", "somereg1", "somereg2" ]`. So, as you can see, the result array consists of the full match followed by all capture groups matches.

And to force a group not to be captured, just delimit with `(?:` and `)`:

```js
"Here is somereg1 and somereg2".match(/.*(?:somereg1).*?(somereg2)/);
// Will result in [ "Here is somereg1 and somereg2", "somereg2" ].
```

Note that the `g` (global) flag changes the return semantics of `match`: they will return an array of full matches and capture groups will be ignored. `exec`, on the other hand, always returns the full match and capture group matches of the match which is after the current [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the `RegExp` instance. For convenience, [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) can be used instead, which returns an iterator of all matches, including all capture groups.

Comment: nice with links! I understand why they behave this way now. Though I don't get why it is designed this way to return sub.parentheses matches?

Comment: It makes sense now. Nice to know how to make it not include these subgroups I was just wondering about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the req. result:

```
var str = "Here is somereg1 and somereg2" //I would expect 
str.match(/(?=(somereg1|somereg2))/)
```

As for the match and exec. I would say go for the match as it uses regex object and prevents you from double escape and all for the strings used as re.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your second line as below:

```
str.match(/somereg1|somereg2/)
```

Comment: Result will be Array [ "somereg1" ]

Comment: Madhura That actually is exactly what I'm looking for! But the only reason I understand why is because of Danilo's answer. But thanks I'm going to use this.